# Row Count and Size For Each Table Under Oracle Schema

Tags: oracle

I need plsql script to find out under schema total row count and size for each table it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select     table_name,     num_rows, bytes/1048576 MB
 from     dba_tables t
Inner join dba_segments s
  On table_name =segment_name and t.owner =s.owner
Where segment_type='TABLE'
And s.owner='schema'
```

Comment: Could you explain where the 1,047,586 comes from? I assumed we would divide by 1,048,576 (1024 * 1024). For my own learning purposes.

Comment: I believe that It is a typo, I am fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is for table size

```
SELECT owner, segment_name, segment_type, tablespace_name, bytes/1048576 MB FROM DBA_SEGMENTS WHERE OWNER = 'table owner' AND SEGMENT_NAME = 'table name' AND SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE';
```

This is for number of rows:

```
select 
   table_name, 
   num_rows counter 
from 
   dba_tables 
where 
   owner = 'XXX'
order by 
   table_name;
```

Please keep in mind that num_rows are estimate and it cannot give you exact number of rows.

For both

```
select     table_name,     num_rows, bytes/1048576 MB
 from     dba_tables t
Inner join dba_segments s
  On table_name =segment_name and t.owner =s.owner
Where segment_type='TABLE'
And s.owner='schema'
```

Comment: i need both size and row count showing together.